# Does the Windows 8 Phone emulator emulate ARM or x86?

Tags: cross-platform, cpu-architecture, emulation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Does anyone know if the Windows 8 Phone emulator uses ARM or x86 for it's CPU architecture?

Comment: There's [a petition for ARM emulator](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/4138536-make-the-emulator-emulate-the-arm-cpu-like-in-win) for Windows Phone; please sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's indeed a x86 virtualization. ARM is only for devices. Inhouse or 3rd party native components need to be build for the both architectures, if you want to test on the emulator.

Comment: Is it even possible to get access to this compiler and a suitable emulator? I'm glad I primarily use .Net because trusting my native code would just work on a completely different architecture seems very risky to me. I'm actually thinking it's a bit risky even for managed code(especially with the WinRT-ish API)

Comment: We use plenty of C++/CX for Skype, and we been using the emulator for many months before Nokia had prototypes ready for us to use.

Answer (score 3):

Emulator is x86, devices are ARM.